# Should i choose GData for youtube or Youtube api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api

I want to integrate youtube in my app for uploading and watching videos so i search on this topic and i found there are two ways to do that.

1. youtube api
2. GData for youtube

Now question is which one i should use to develop my application and which is more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are good, but to increase your efficience, i would suggest to use Gdata, because it makes certain tasks easier... you should take a look in this link, for the [Objective-C Gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).r